# Get Properties of an Object Passed to a Method c#

Tags: c#, object, properties

I am trying to pass an object to a method and then match the properties of the object to column names in a datatable. The object I am passing is of type "IndividualDetails." The following code works well, but is there a way to be more generic and pass any type of object and not have to specifically specify the "IndividualDetails" type in the code. Please see the typeof() line.

I would like to be able to map properties to columns of a datatable for multiple types of objects.

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
List<IndividualDetails> individuals = new List<IndividualDetails>(); 
int[] index = ProcessX(ds.Tables["PersonsTable"], individuals);


private static int[] ProcessX(DataTable t, object p)
    {

        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(IndividualDetails).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);


    Console.WriteLine("PROPERTIES:  "+p.GetType());
    for (int x = 0; x < Props.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(Propsx[x].Name);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();

        int[] pos = new int[t.Columns.Count]; 
        for (int x = 0; x < t.Columns.Count; x++)
        {
            pos[x] = -1; 
            for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
            {
                if (t.Columns[x].ColumnName.CompareTo(Props[i].Name) == 0)
                {
                    pos[x] = i; 
                }
            }

        }

        return pos;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make this a generic method and use the Type reference to pull out the properties. So instead of this:

```
private static int[] ProcessX(DataTable t, object p)
{
  PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(IndividualDetails).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Do this:

```
private static int[] ProcessX<T>(DataTable t, object p)
{
  PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your code right, you should be able to do this:

```
private static int[] ProcessX<T>(DataTable t, T obj)
    {

        PropertyInfo[] Props = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: Actually, there's no need to make the method generic, since `obj.GetType()` will use the run-time type of `obj`, not the compile-time type.

Comment: I just tried passing an object versus a List<object> and it works. I will also try your version above too. Thanks for the quick response.